# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError with MomentJS fromNow() - Angular 5

Tags: angular, momentjs

I'm developing an app using Angular 5, which receives a lot of data through websockets (using Socket.IO) in a service, passes it to a component trough `Subjects`, and then, that component, gives an object (which is updated through the `websockets/subjects`) as input to another component. This last component, displays the information.

One of the information I need to display is "how long ago did something happened", and to do it, i'm receiving a timestamp, and parsing it with MomentJS, and then using MomentJS's `fromNow()` to display the "how long ago it did happen", but, I'm getting a

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'hace unos segundos'. Current
>   value: 'hace un minuto'.

What I have read is that I can use `ChangeDetectorRef's detechChanges()` when I update the value, but it didn't solve it. From what I see, is that my problem is not from updating the value, it is because the `fromNow()` return value changes from "a few seconds ago" to "a minute ago" in the instant that Angular makes the checks. Is there some way I can workaround this error?

Logic of my app explained a little better:

Websocket data -> SocketioService receives it -> Service pushes data through a Subject to ShovelsComponent -> ShovelsComponent updates the data in an object (there is one for each shovel). ShovelsComponent has a lot of ShovelComponent childrens -> ShovelsComponent passes this object as Input to ShovelComponent, which displays the info of the object. -> ShovelComponent throws the error when the value of displayLastLoop() changes.

```
displayLastLoop() {
  if (this.shovel.lastLoop) {
    return this.shovel.lastLoop.fromNow();
  } else {
    return '[Sin información]';
  }
}
```

I tried using ChangeDetectorRef's detectChanges() after I update the value in ShovelsComponent, and inside displayLastLoop(). The first aproach did nothing, and the second threw me some kind of backtracking error.

Comment: Don't use fromNow() when displaying the object. Indeed, the change detection will detect changes in the displayed value although nothing is supposed to have changed (which causes the error). Instead, when updating the objects, compute the fromNow(), and store the result in the object. Or, if you want the displayed value to change dynamically, even if there is no update, then use a component which takes the lastLoop as input, computes, stores and displays the fromNow, and recomputes it every minute or so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was about to try this out, when i found something called: angular2-moment, which has a pipe called amTimeAgo, that does practically the same than fromNow(). For now, i haven't seen the error again, so I'm guessing it fixed it!